# How to enforce variable as a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have

```
e1 = x
e2 = x^2
e3 = x^3
```

And I do

```
Solve[3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3 == v1*e1 + v2*e2 + v3*e3, {v1, v2, v3}]
```

which returns

```
v3 -> -(v1/x^2) - v2/x - (-3 - 4 x - x^2)/x^2
```

instead of just 3,4 and 1. How do I make Mathematica treat the v's as constants or numbers instead of functions? `Reduce` does not really help because then it starts considering imaginary parts of x and what not.

**EDIT** The idea is that I am defining a polynomial basis; and I want the representation of some given polynomial in terms of that basis. `CoefficientList` will work for the canonical basis (which is the above); but not for others

Comment: In this case, if you just want the coefficients, a way is to use `CoefficienList[3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3]` and equate the coefficients to `V1,V2,V3`...

Comment: The idea is that I am defining a polynomial basis; and I want the representation of some given polynomial in terms of that basis. `CoefficientList` will work for the canonical basis (which is the above); but not for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function to do exactly what you demand:

```
SolveAlways[3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3 == v1*e1 + v2*e2 + v3*e3, {x}]
(*{{v1 -> 3, v2 -> 4, v3 -> 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `PolynomialQuotientRemainder[]`:

```
FoldList[PolynomialQuotientRemainder[Last[#1], #2, x] &,
         {0, 3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3}, {x^3, x^2, x}][[2 ;;, 1]]
  (* {1, 4, 3} *)
```

A more complicated example:

```
FoldList[PolynomialQuotientRemainder[Last[#1], #2, x] &,
         {0, 3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3}, ChebyshevU[Range[3, 0, -1], x]][[2 ;;, 1]]
  (* {1/8, 1, 7/4, 1} *)
```

Check:

```
%.ChebyshevU[Range[3, 0, -1], x] == 3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3 // Simplify
  (* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e1 = x;
e2 = x^2;
e3 = x^3;

eqn = 3 x + 4 x^2 + x^3 == v1*e1 + v2*e2 + v3*e3;

Solve[CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ eqn, {v1, v2, v3}][[1]]

(*  {v1 -> 3, v2 -> 4, v3 -> 1}  *)
```